# Funcionalidad extra a codigo ya creado

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un codigo donde debo agregar una funcionalidad.
De hecho, fui agregando algunas como buscarAutos, vanderAutos, autosParaLaVenta, etc y todos funcionan pero esta ultima, me tira un error y no logro ver cual es.
La consigna:
Resulta que a la concesionaria le suelen preguntar muy seguido cuáles de los autos para la venta son 0 km. Tené que un auto 0 km es aquel que tenga un kilometraje menor a 100. **Vas a tener que desarrollar la funcionalidad autosNuevos.**

¿Cómo podés resolver esto reutilizando la función autosParaLaVenta?

Para comenzar, tenés que agregar el código que escribiste en el ejercicio anterior.

Mi codigo:

```
let autos = [{
    marca: "Ford",
    modelo: "Fiesta",
    color: "Azul",
    precio: 150000,
    km: 200,
    cuotas: 12,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: "APL123",
    vendido: false
},{
    marca: "Toyota",
    modelo: "Corolla",
    color: "Blanco",
    precio: 100000,
    km: 0,
    cuotas: 14,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: "JJK116",
    vendido: false
}];

let concesionaria = {
   autos: autos,
   buscarAuto: function(patente){
      for(let i = 0;i<autos.length;i++){
         if(autos[i].patente == patente) {
            return autos[i];
         }
      }
      return null;
},
venderAuto: function(patente){
   if(this.buscarAuto(patente) != null){
      let index = autos.indexOf(this.buscarAuto(patente));
      autos[index].vendido = true;
      }
},
autosParaLaVenta: function(){
return autos = this.autos.filter(function (elemento){
      return !elemento.vendido
   })
},
autosNuevos : function(autos){
 const auto = this.autosParaLaVenta(function(autos){

     if (auto.km<100){
         return auto
     }
 });

}           

}
```

Y el error que me da es:

- Al llamar a la función autosNuevos debe devolver los el auto que originalmente no cumple con los requisitos
- Al vender al auto con patente 'JJK116' y luego llamar a la función autos0KM no debe contener ese auto

Comment: Osea, primero debes efectivamente mediante la función _autosParaLaVenta_ traer los autos que puedes vender, y luego filtrar ese listado con la condición que necesitas para diferenciar un auto nuevo de uno antiguo.

Comment: revisa tu funcion autorsNuevos la parte autoParaLaVenta no lleva argumento, al resultado de llamar esa funcion es cuando debes filtrar.